# Character vectors in R from the command line

Tags: r, command-line, character

I'm trying to run an R script from the command line. Everything works except part of the code takes in a character vector, which I pass into the R script as a command line prompt.

Example:
Command line Arg: "A,B,C,D,E"

needs to be converted to:

c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `strsplit("A,B,C,D,E", split=",")` will help.

Comment: so would I just do x <- c(strsplit("A,B,C,D,E", split=","))?

Comment: In that instance the `c(.)` is probably ineffective. You would probably want `unlist`.

Answer (score 0):

@Imo has suggested `strsplit` but that's only possibily useful if you have named argument with the value of "A,B,C,D,E". Which is not yet clear that you know how to obtain. The `commandArgs` function is used to pull in the command from a script and it has a parameter to drop everything after the `--args` flag: So this might work:

```
  inp <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
  desired <- scan(text=inp, sep=",", what="")
  ### Now do the rest of your processing with that character vector.
```

The default separator for `scan` is whitespace and the default "what" is "numeric", so those need to be specified. `scan` is the function underlying the `read.*` family .

Answer (score 0):

Just use the command `set x=c("A","B","C","D")`